# migrateuser works but how to take care of MySites

Tags: migration, domain, mysite

We have over 2,000 mysites and it looks like are not propagated to mysite and it's contents. Also the url does not change to new domain_user url. What are the steps as company is going to be another domain?

```
STSADM -o migrateuser -oldlogin olddomain\userA -newlogin newdomain\UserA -ignoresidhistory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move-spuser and it will take care of it.

What you need to do, you can turn off the "MySite Cleanup Job" in the Timer Job Definitions.in order to avoid any deletion or disabling of mysite.

One more thing, Please take the backup of your Mysite content DBs before migration. just for safe playing.

Comment: Would this work when mysite user have it's own content database? More than 350 heavy mysite users have their own content database as opposed to global mysite database. Please reply. Is there any other way to Just care of the mysite?

Comment: it will take care of all mysites. this command have nothing with content DBs, it just move the properties from old to new login and relink the mysite.